# Is rippleEffect private API? IOS

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi, catransition

just as the title. Is `rippleEffect` the type of `CATransition` private API?

```
CATransition * canimation = [CATransition animation];
[canimation setDelegate:self];
[canimation setDuration:0.5];
canimation.timingFunction = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut;
canimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards;
canimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[canimation setType:@"rippleEffect"];
[card.layer addAnimation:canimation forKey:@"animation"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's private.  If it were public, there would be a constant defined for it in a QuartzCore header file, named something like `kCATransitionRipple`.  No constant = not public.